# Can't add more than one record, ID not autoincrimenting

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to add site details to a database and then after I insert a row, output the result to a TextView. The record is being inserted into the database because it's being shown in a TextView, however I can only insert one record and I'm not sure why. I'm been using the tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aui-kFuXFYE) and modifying it to meet my needs.

Here is my DBAdapter:

```
public class DBAdapter {

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Constants & Data
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // For logging:
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    // DB Fields
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
    /*
     * CHANGE 1:
     */
    // TODO: Setup your fields here:
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_PORT = "port";

    // TODO: Setup your field numbers here (0 = KEY_ROWID, 1=...)
    public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
    public static final int COL_ADDRESS = 2;
    public static final int COL_USERNAME = 3;
    public static final int COL_PASSWORD = 4;
    public static final int COL_PORT = 5;

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_PORT };

    // DB info: it's name, and the table we are using (just one).
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Sites";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "SiteTable";
    // Track DB version if a new version of your app changes the format.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " ("
            + KEY_ROWID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

            /*
             * CHANGE 2:
             */
            // TODO: Place your fields here!
            // + KEY_{...} + " {type} not null"
            // - Key is the column name you created above.
            // - {type} is one of: text, integer, real, blob
            // (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
            // - "not null" means it is a required field (must be given a
            // value).
            // NOTE: All must be comma separated (end of line!) Last one must
            // have NO comma!!
            + KEY_NAME + " string not null, " + KEY_ADDRESS
            + " string not null, " + KEY_USERNAME + " string not null, "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " string not null, " + KEY_PORT
            + " integer not null"

            // Rest of creation:
            + ");";

    // Context of application who uses us.
    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Public methods:
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    // Open the database connection.
    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Close the database connection.
    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Add a new set of values to the database.
    public long insertRow(String name, String address, String username,
            String password, int port) {
        /*
         * CHANGE 3:
         */
        // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
        // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
        // Create row's data:
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PORT, port);
        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    // Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    // Return all data in the database.
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Get a specific row (by rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
    public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String address,
            String username, String password, String port) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

        /*
         * CHANGE 4:
         */
        // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
        // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
        // Create row's data:
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        newValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        newValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        // newValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        // newValues.put(KEY_PORT, port);

        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
    }

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Private Helper Classes:
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading. Used to
     * handle low-level database access.
     */
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version "
                    + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                    + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm querying the database here:

```
public class FTPConnector extends Activity {
DBAdapter myDb;
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.ftp);

            status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
            editAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
            editUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
            editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
            addsiteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addsiteBtn);
            addsiteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    siteManager();

                }
            });
            openDb();
        }

        private void openDb() {
            myDb = new DBAdapter(this);
            myDb.open();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            closeDb();
        }

        private void closeDb() {
            myDb.close();
        }

        //Where the insertRecord() happens
            public void siteManager() {
                    final AlertDialog customDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.site_manager, null);
                    final EditText tmpname = (EditText) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogsitename);
                    final EditText tmpaddress = (EditText) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogaddress);
                    final EditText tmpuser = (EditText) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogusername);
                    final EditText tmppass = (EditText) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogpassword);
                    final EditText tmpport = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogport);
                    final TextView tmpsites = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                    final CheckBox tmppassive = (CheckBox) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialogpassive);
                    final Button tmpclose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
                    final Button tmptestBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.testBtn);
                    final Button tmpsavetsite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.saveSite);

                    customDialog.setView(tmpclose);
                    customDialog.setView(tmptestBtn);
                    customDialog.setView(tmpname);
                    customDialog.setView(tmpaddress);
                    customDialog.setView(tmpuser);
                    customDialog.setView(tmppass);
                    customDialog.setView(tmpport);
                    customDialog.setView(tmppassive);
                    customDialog.setView(tmpsavetsite);
                    customDialog.setView(tmpsites);

                    tmpclose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            customDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    tmptestBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            _name = tmpname.getText().toString();
                            _address = tmpaddress.getText().toString();
                            _user = tmpuser.getText().toString();
                            _pass = tmppass.getText().toString();
                            _port = Integer.parseInt(tmpport.getText().toString());

                            _passive = false;
                            if (tmppassive.isChecked()) {
                                _passive = true;
                            }

                            boolean status = ftpConnect(_address, _user, _pass, _port);

                            if (status == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(FTPConnector.this, "Connection Succesful",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(FTPConnector.this,
                                        "Connection Failed:" + status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();

                            }
                        }
                    });

                    tmpsavetsite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            tmpsites.setText("");
                            String msg = "!";
                            _name = tmpname.getText().toString();
                            _address = tmpaddress.getText().toString();
                            _user = tmpuser.getText().toString();
                            _pass = tmppass.getText().toString();
                            _port = Integer.parseInt(tmpport.getText().toString());

                            long newId = myDb.insertRow(_name, _address, _user, _pass, 21);

                            Cursor c = myDb.getAllRows();

                            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                int id = c.getInt(0);
                                String _name = c.getString(1);
                                String _address = c.getString(2);
                                String _user = c.getString(3);
                                String _pass = c.getString(4);
                                int _port = c.getInt(5);

                                msg += "id=" + id + "\n";
                                msg += ", name=" + _name + "\n";
                                msg += ", address=" + _address + "\n";
                                msg += ", username=" + _user + "\n";
                                msg += ", password=" + _pass + "\n";
                                msg += ", port=" + _port + "\n";

                                while (c.moveToNext());
                            }
                            c.close();
                            // displayText(msg);
                            tmpsites.setText(msg);
                        }
                    });
                    customDialog.setView(view);
                    customDialog.show();
                }
```

Why can't I add more than one record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here :

```
 while (c.moveToNext());  //<<<
```

currently you are not using any loop like `do-while` for iterating through cursor(*you forget to add do block with while*). get all data from cursor as using for loop:

```
//more to the first row
 c.moveToFirst();

//iterate over rows
 for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {

    // get all data here from current row..

    //move to the next row
    c.moveToNext();
 }
//close the cursor
c.close();
```

and using `do-while` you can get all values from current row as:

```
  c.moveToFirst();   //more to the first row
    do {
        // get all data here from current row..
     } while (c.moveToNext());
```